# If I block a creature with afflict and my blocker kills that creature, will I still take afflict damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent controls [Neheb, the Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNeheb%2c%20the%20Eternal%5d) (a 6/5 creature with afflict 3), and attacks me with it. If I block Neheb with a creature that will kill it, will I still take damage from afflict?

Comment: Yes. In fact, you will lose 3 life before creatures deal damage to each to each other.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, you still lose life from Afflict**

You even do so long before your opponent's creature dies - Afflict is a triggered ability that triggers when a player declares a blocker for that creature. What happens to that creature afterwards is irrelevant to this ability. Also note that it's not damage, but loss of life.

> **702.129a** Afflict is a triggered ability. “Afflict N” means “Whenever this creature becomes blocked, defending player loses N life.”

So, in your Declare Blockers step, Afflict triggers, eventually resolves, and causes you to lose 3 life. Following that step is the Combat Damage Step, in which your creature will deal lethal damage to your opponent's creature.